# view.measure() throwing null exception

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

While working on page rendering in the Xamarin I am encountering the app crash when OnLayout is called. The `view.Measure(msw,msh)` is throwing null exception.

```
protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
{
    base.OnLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);

    var msw = MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(r - l, MeasureSpecMode.Exactly);
    var msh = MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(b - t, MeasureSpecMode.Exactly);

    view.Measure(msw, msh);
    view.Layout(0, 0, r - l, b - t);
}
```

`

Comment: `...throwing null exception...` Are you saying `view` is null? Where are you assigning it... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it?rq=1

Comment: Sorry I meant "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" this. I am assigning view = LayoutInflater.From(this.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.CameraLayout, this, false);

Comment: Sounds like your LayoutInflater.From is returning null.

Comment: Are you using a fragment?

Comment: It is working now as the resource layout file was not updated.